# Encoding issue of arguments for BULK INSERT via SSMS

Tags: sql, character-encoding, sql-server-2008-r2, bulkinsert

So I stumbled on an interesting problem while trying to load some data.  Essentially I have some files with data in them that I am trying to BULK INSERT into a table with varchar columns to make it easy to import.  The file is tab delimited with CRLFs as the row terminator.

For some reason, when I write/copy&paste the BULK INSERT command from my own PC the command fails.  It offers an error stating

```
Bulk load: DataFileType was incorrectly specified as widechar.  DataFileType will be assumed to be char because the data file does not have a Unicode signature.
```

Then it says:

```
Bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 7.  Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.
```

The command is as follows:

```
BULK INSERT <table>
 FROM '<filepath>'
  WITH 
   (
  DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar',
  FIELDTERMINATOR = ' ',
  ROWTERMINATOR = '
 '
  );
```

Now, the part that doesn't make sense is that without changing any piece of that code, my co-worker was able to run and load the table with perfect success.  No warning messages, no failures, nothing.

When I look at the command in Notepad++ with all character symbols enabled it appears to be correct with CRLFs as the row endings and arrows to denote tabs between columns.

The only thing I could come up with on my own is that somehow the encoding of my SQL Server Management Studio text editor must be messing up the field/row terminator arguments and causing the bulk insert command to fail.

Anyone have any bright ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my coworker's computer is messed up and does something weird with encoding that enables him to just paste LFs correctly.

I was able to solve my problem by creating some dynamic sql to execute the bulk insert with the row terminator being generated by CHAR(10) concatenated to the rest of the command.

CHAR(10) is the ascii representation of a linefeed which was the row terminator in the files I had.